# Sending UDP socket in linux - C language

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp

I know that this is obviously elementary question and I know that there are many tutorials and ready-to-go examples but I must missing something. I am trying to send for example text (`char *`) via UDP socket to other machine in local network. So far I tried some tutorials like http://gafferongames.com/networking-for-game-programmers/sending-and-receiving-packets/ and so on but I always get error in `bind()` function with errno "Cannot assign requested address".

I just have some data in char array and I want to push them via network to another host. Could someone please point me to the right direction? Do I need socket server or client? Do I need to bind the socket to some interface?

This is my playground:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>

int handle;

int init_socket()
{
        handle = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

        if (handle <= 0)
        {
                printf("failed to create socket\n");
                return 1;
        }

        printf("sockets successfully initialized\n");

        return 0;
}

int main ()
{
        unsigned short port = 30000;
    char * data = "hovno";

    init_socket();

        struct sockaddr_in address;

    memset((char *) &address, 0, sizeof(address));

        address.sin_family = AF_INET;
        address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.11.129"); // this is address of host which I want to send the socket
        address.sin_port = htons(port);


    printf("handle: %d\n", handle); // prints number greater than 0 so I assume handle is initialized properly

        if (bind(handle, (const struct sockaddr*) &address, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) < 0)
        {
                printf("failed to bind socket (%s)\n", strerror(errno)); // Cannot assign requested address
                return 1;
        }

        int nonBlocking = 1;
        if (fcntl(handle, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK, nonBlocking) == -1)
        {
                printf("failed to set non-blocking\n");
                return 2;
        }

        int sent_bytes = sendto(handle, data, strlen(data), 0, (const struct sockaddr*) &address, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

        if (sent_bytes != strlen(data))
        {
                printf("failed to send packet\n");
                return 3;
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should `bind` the _local_ address (or do not bind it at all if you don't care about the port number of the sending socket). The remote address is specified in 'sendto'. You cannot bind the remote address to local socket, it's not how `bind` works.
You still need to call `bind` on the server side to specify the port number.

Comment: I try to send data so this is where I should use server part of udp socket? So I need to bind two addresses? First address would be my local address of server and in `sendto` part I specify address which I would like to send the data? I need to specify the exact port because I try to send this data to VoIP client so this client can process data in right way (client listens on specific port).

Comment: The sending side should call `socket` and `sendto`. No need to call `bind`, you don't have to adjust local address of the socket. The remote address is specified in `sendto`.
Just remove the 'bind' part from your code, it should work then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bind` is called for the *local* address (one you intend to `recv` packets to). The IP address must be a local IP address of the machine, or (most frequently) `INADDR_ANY`.

Normally you don't have to use `bind` on the client side at all. The system will pick a suitable free port for you automatically.

To specify the remote address for a UDP socket, use `sendto`, not `send`.

If you search Google for `udp client c code`, one of the first results is [this one](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~almeroth/classes/W01.176B/hw2/examples/udp-client.c). You can see that the networking part is basically just two calls, `socket` and `sendto`.